# Install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 8.1

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1

I have a problem when i try to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 8.1 64 bit. it boot normally but when it reach the step where it detect Windows 8.1 and ask me if i want to install Ubuntu alongside with win. it say : Erase disk and install Ubuntu.
Please help me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many install options: dual boot, delete everything there and install Ubuntu, various ways to partition the disk (some are destructive to existing content), etc.  Some of the options are worded in a confusing way.  I accidentally wiped out Windows because I didn't understand one of the partitioning options.  Before you install, make sure you fully understand any option you want to select.  It can take some research.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1" although in some cases it might not exist. In any case, do not use "Erase the disk and install Ubuntu". There should be "Something else" right at the bottom of the dialog. Choose it and configure partitions:  mount "/" and swap. Although the last case is risky beaucase you can broke the bootloader.

Comment: Yes there is this option, but it shows that the HDD is free ( i mean 500 GB free space although i am running win 8.1 and i have many files there ! ).